# How to grep the output from first grep of the date?

Tags: unix

I would like to search from the first output of grep. First grep I search all the files from yesterday that has the word "abc". I would like to also find if it has "def" from first search.

This is what I have

```
find /tttt/aaaa/bbb -type f -mtime -1 -mtime 0 -print0| xargs -0 grep -l "abc"
```

I would like to find the output that also contains "def".

Comment: Why not just use arguments to the `find` command, like `-name` or `-regex`? Or .. are you looking for files that have those strings in the *content*?  If so, what about `-exec grep -q ...`?

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to search for multiple strings in a list. This can be accomplished with the -E switch on grep. This allows you to provide search strings separated with a pipe.

```
grep -E 'abc|def'
```

Another option is to use a backslash on the pipe:

```
grep 'abc\|def'
```

EDIT: Oops. I thought you wanted an OR, but you want an AND.

You just need to add another pipe to grep at the end of your one-liner:

```
| xargs grep -l 'def'
```

Comment: when I tried this find /tttt/aaaa/bbb -type f -mtime -1 -mtime 0 -print0| xargs -0 grep -l -E"abc|def"  , this gives the result of those file has def only as well. I would like it has both though.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you are wanting. Providing sample data in your question would be helpful. I don't think you want to use the -l switch in grep.

Comment: I want to go through all logs files in the path. and only search those logs dated yesterday. and in the logs it has "abc" and "def"

Comment: The log FILENAME should have "abc" and "def", or the log CONTENT should have them?